# Generate completely unique message

Tags: winapi, message

In my code, I subclass a control (UserForm) from another application which may define messages in the `WM_USER` and `WM_APP` ranges. I would like therefore to generate a unique message to send to the control I subclass, which definitely has no existing meaning.

Is there any safe way to do this; [`RegisterWindowMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagea) takes a string parameter, what if my string clashes with one the parent app has already defined?

I have no control over the app whose control I subclass.

There are other ways to solve this problem, but sending a custom message is the cleanest, and I'm wondering if there's a safe way to do that.

Comment: One (possibly naive) solution would be to keep calling the function until successful. Try "FOO". Failed. "Try FOO1". Success.

Comment: @Lundin No the issue is, _"If two different applications register the same message string, the applications return the same message value"_ - so when I say "clash" I mean that I (successfully) generate a message which already has meaning to the Application that owns the control I'm subclassing

Comment: *what if my string clashes with one the parent app has already defined* use guid string for *RegisterWindowMessage*. the probability of conflict is zero

Comment: @RbMm Unless the parent app has guessed it, but yes that sounds like a sensible workaround. Besides, if they've done that then really they deserve to have their messages eaten by my subclass

Comment: There is no way to guess a random GUID.

Comment: @Greedo - if you create random guid probability that somebody another will use it is zero. also - you use some executable file (name/path) from where your code run ? what if somebody will be use the same path\name for file and conflict with your ?

Comment: If you are afraid of UUID collisions, you should be playing the lottery instead. Chances of winning are **much** higher than hitting a version-4 UUID [collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions). @rbm: The probability is higher than zero.

Comment: @IInspectable - theoretical yes. in practice - 0. faster can be collision with file path\name - when another program select the same

Comment: The probability is non-zero in practice, too.

Comment: @IInspectable - even if assume another app use guid too - 2^128 variants of guids - non zero ?

Comment: @rbm: There are 122 random bits in a version-4 UUID, not 128. And yes, the probability of a collision is non-zero.

Comment: `which may define messages in the WM_USER and WM_APP ranges` - the `WM_USER` [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-user) is `0x0400 - 0x7FFF`, the `WM_APP` range is `0x8000 - 0xBFFF`, `RegisterWindowMessage` [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagea) `0xC000 - 0xFFFF`. So if the subclassed app *indeed* defines private message in the `WM_USER` and the `WM_APP` range, you will never clash with them using `RegisterWindowMessage`.

Comment: @GSerg unless they also do that (I don't know either way) and the string they use for `RegisterWindowMessage` is by some tiny chance the same one I use.